# How do I convert matrix of RAW values to matrix of RGB values in code?

Tags: image-processing, rawimage

I have a bunch of values that seem to be 12-bit numbers.  If I put them in a matrix and scale each one to a value 0-255 and then show them as an image, I get something that looks like a photo, but it's quite bland.

I think that they might be direct reading off of a camera sensor.  They have a sort of stippled pattern, kind of like plaid, that makes me think that they might be a sort of Bayer filter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter

I want to convert these number into RGB values.  What do I need to do?  For each 2x2 in the Bayer pattern, do I convert the red to R, blue to B, and then average the green values?  Do I need a gamma correction?

I noticed that the max value is much lower than the full 0xfff.  Do I need to scale the values?

Comment: In case it is Bayer CFA, you may use OpenCV `cvtColor` method with one of the 4 options: `COLOR_BayerBG2BGR`, `COLOR_BayerGB2BGR`, `COLOR_BayerRG2BGR`, `COLOR_BayerGR2BGR`. In case it's a raw image, you may have to apply white balance, gamma, and contrast enhancement. It's hard to answer without the raw data file. Can you please share it?

Comment: I'm unable to share it because it is proprietary, sorry.  Are those four options the four different Bayer filter patterns?  I have tried all four patterns and none of them were perfect.

Comment: Yes, Bayer pattern has only 4 options (out of 2x2 pixels 2 pixels are green in the diagonal, one is red and one is blue). There are many other CFA options, but Bayer is the most common.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is well-described here: https://www.strollswithmydog.com/raw-file-conversion-steps/

Looks like I was getting it mostly right by the problem was grey balance.  There is a transformation that needs to be made on the sensor values to map it to the 0-255 RGB component and the transform that needs to be made depends on the color.  The best way is to take a photo of a perfect grey and calibrate.